# How do I find out which `map` ruleset matched?

Tags: nginx

```
map "$request_uri $http_referer $http_user_agent $http_cookie" $flag {
    default 0;
    # rules
    "~test" 1;
    "~1234" 1;
    # …
}
```

```
location ~ example {
    if (\$flag = 1) {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/flag.log;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to know which of the `map` rules and what part of `$request_uri $http_referer $http_user_agent $http_cookie` matched?

I need this for debugging purposes. If the log gets flooded, it's hard to tell which of the `map` rules has an error and causes false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named capture in a `map`. The defined variable can be used to form the map result or anywhere else in your configuration after the map has been evaluated.

For example:

```
map ... $flag {
    default         0;
    ~(?<mymap>test) 1;
    ~(?<mymap>1234) 1;
}
...
if ($flag) { ... }
```

The `if` block will evaluate the value of `$flag` and if the regular expression containing the named capture is reached, the value of `$mymap` will be set to `test` or `1234`.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!